# SQL Query Error - If Else Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The following SQl query gives me the error:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1') 
UPDATE comments SET page1='exists' WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1' 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO comments (user_id,course_id,page1) VALUES ('2','1','inserted')
```

**" #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1') UPDATE co' at line 1 "**

I'm sure the syntax is correct?!

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a standalone piece of SQL (in which case having a unique key on user_id and course_id , then using `INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would be easier), or as lines within a stored procedure?

Comment: I am trying to run this as a SQL query via phpMyAdmin

Comment: Then that is not valid SQL. IF is a flow control statement, and with a raw SQL query there is no flow to control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique key covering user_id and course_id

Then just use

```
INSERT INTO comments (user_id,course_id,page1) 
VALUES ('2','1','inserted')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page1='exists'
```

Comment: Thanks Kickstart that works perfect in phpMyAdmin. Although using this SQL statement in php doesn't seem to work. Inserting works but i assume its the duplicate key part that's causing the problems. Is there anyway around this? Sorry i thought if it works in phpMyAdmin it would also work in php.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**IF-statement**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) syntax:

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1') THEN 
    UPDATE comments SET page1='exists' WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1';
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO comments (user_id,course_id,page1) VALUES ('2','1','inserted');
```

**OR**

As per me you have to make practice of **BEGIN...END** block as shown below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1') THEN 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE comments SET page1='exists' WHERE user_id='2' AND course_id='1';
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO comments (user_id,course_id,page1) VALUES ('2','1','inserted');
END
```

My above queries will work in Procedures(PL-SQL). If you want to use above query in SQL
then use below code:

Create a [**UNIQUE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-primary-key.html) constraint on your `user_id & course_id` columns, if one does not already exist:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD UNIQUE (user_id,course_id);
```

Use [**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO comments (user_id,course_id,page1) 
VALUES ('2','1','inserted') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page1='exists'
```

Comment: I don't think that is valid MySQL syntax

Comment: Did you try it? There is no `IF` statement in SQL (and neither in MySQL's SQL dialect)

Comment: Thanks for you efforts Saharsh however this still doesn't work